# yarn on AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dockerfile, yarnpkg

Did anyone manage to get [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) installed and working on AWS Lambda?

(I'm trying to create a function that can build small React projects)

Currently I have yarn installed and working in a Docker image (based on public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2), but while running it in the Lambda environment I'm getting permission errors when yarn tries to access the read-only file system.

Dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2
...
# Update yum
RUN yum -y update
# Install NodeJS
RUN curl -fsSL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x \
    | bash - && yum -y install nodejs
# Install Yarn
RUN curl -fsSL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo \
    | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && \
    rpm --import https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/pubkey.gpg && \
    yum -y install yarn
# Copy Binaries
RUN cp -r \
    /usr/share/yarn/bin/* \
    /usr/bin/corepack /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm /usr/bin/npx \
    /opt/bin/
# Copy Libraries
RUN cp -r \
    /usr/share/yarn/lib/* \
    /usr/lib/node_modules \
    /opt/lib/
# Configure NPM & Yarn
RUN npm config set prefix /tmp/npm/
RUN yarn config set prefix /tmp/yarn/
...
```

Errors:

```
>yarn install
warning Cannot find a suitable global folder. Tried these: "/usr/local, /home/sbx_user1051/.yarn"
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'
Could not set cachedir: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/tmp/yum-sbx_user1051-eC5Oqk'
Error making cache directory: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/amzn2-core error was: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/cache/yum'
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

*** edit ***

**With global flag**

```
>yarn --global-folder /tmp/yarn/ install
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/home/sbx_user1051/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable.
warning Selected the next writable cache folder in the list, will be "/tmp/.yarn-cache-993".
warning Cannot find a suitable global folder. Tried these: "/usr/local, /home/sbx_user1051/.yarn"
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'
Could not set cachedir: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/tmp/yum-sbx_user1051-3FcZxd'
Error making cache directory: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/amzn2-core error was: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/cache/yum'
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Writing to `'/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'`, `'/var/cache/yum'` etc. is not allowed - try to find a setting that allows you to set it up so it only writes to `/tmp/ as that is the only directory that you're allowed to write to in an AWS Lambda function. Anywhere else, and you're not allowed.

Comment: Try doing `yarn --global-folder /tmp/yarn/ install`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I tried and failed. Post edited.

Comment: Not really related to Lambda but more re: `yarn` - try to tag it as yarn and see what commands will make everything run under the /tmp directory would be my advise (while abstracting out anything about Lambda) - pose it as a general question regarding telling yarn to operate everything from one folder